# CRAN install of devtools 2.0 fails on CentOS 7.4

Tags: r, devtools

I'm trying to install the latest `devtools` from `CRAN`. It's failing on install with some poorly defined segfault. Is this indicative of some kind of R distribution error?

```
 *** caught segfault ***

address (nil), cause 'unknown'

Traceback:
 1: fun(libname, pkgname)
 2: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 3: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 4: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 5: tryCatch(fun(libname, pkgname), error = identity)
 6: runHook(".onLoad", env, package.lib, package)
 7: loadNamespace(name)
 8: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 9: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
10: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
11: tryCatch(loadNamespace(name), error = function(e) stop(e))
12: getNamespace(ns)
13: asNamespace(ns)
14: getExportedValue(pkg, name)
15: ps::ps_is_supported
16: fun(libname, pkgname)
17: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
18: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
19: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
20: tryCatch(fun(libname, pkgname), error = identity)
21: runHook(".onLoad", env, package.lib, package)
22: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
23: asNamespace(ns)
24: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
25: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
26: asNamespace(ns)
27: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
28: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
29: asNamespace(ns)
30: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
31: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc, keep.source, partial = TRUE)
32: withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
33: suppressPackageStartupMessages(loadNamespace(package, lib.loc,     keep.source, partial = TRUE))
34: code2LazyLoadDB(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source,     compress = compress)
35: makeLazyLoading(pkg_name, lib, keep.source = keep.source)
36: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
37: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
38: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
39: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        sm <- strsplit(conditionMessage(e), "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && isTRUE(getOption("show.error.messages"))) {        cat(msg, file = outFile)        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
40: try({    suppressPackageStartupMessages(.getRequiredPackages(quietly = TRUE))    makeLazyLoading(pkg_name, lib, keep.source = keep.source)})
41: do_install_source(pkg_name, instdir, pkg, desc)
42: do_install(pkg)
43: tools:::.install_packages()
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
```

Some additional context:

I am running a custom compiled build of R 3.5.1 for openBLAS and am setting a custom personal directory to install packages.

Comment: (Probably) related: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1292

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely the result of a broken package in your package library, but you would need to give more context to know for certain.